# tkz-euclide Change Axes Names

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Is it possible to rename the default x and y axes when using `\tkzAxeXY` to something like `Re` and `Im` for complex Numbers?

For example, I have this code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=2,ymax=2,xmin=-2,ymin=-2]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(0, sqrt(2)){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,-1){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(-1,1){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2,2){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,-2){F}
    \tkzDefCircle[through](A,B)
    \tkzDrawLine[add= 0.1 and 0,color=blue, dashed](E,D)
    \tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0.1, color=blue, dashed](C,F)
    \tkzDrawLine[color=green,add=0 and 0](D,C)
    \tkzDrawCircle[dashed, color=red](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image: circles]

But I basically want this:

[image: imaginaryCircles]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure whether there exists a better way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=2,ymax=2,xmin=-2,ymin=-2]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY[/tkzdrawX/label=Re,/tkzdrawY/label=Im]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(0, sqrt(2)){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,-1){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(-1,1){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2,2){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,-2){F}
    \tkzDefCircle[through](A,B)
    \tkzDrawLine[add= 0.1 and 0,color=blue, dashed](E,D)
    \tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0.1, color=blue, dashed](C,F)
    \tkzDrawLine[color=green,add=0 and 0](D,C)
    \tkzDrawCircle[dashed, color=red](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it works, it's already a good way. Thank you very much!